# is it possible to store files(.txt, .csv, etc) and not its contents to postgresql using Java JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

this is what I'am aiming to do;

1. Student records are stored in a text file (StudentRecords.txt)
2. Store this text file into my postgresql database using Java JDBC
3. Retrieve the file, read its content and display it into the console/servlet/jsp etc.

on my research, I found out that I can use CLOB to store text files into my database, but postgresql doesn't support it.

What is the best approach in dealing with this kind of file types using postgresql along with Java and JDBC?

Also, is it good to stored files(text files, images etc) into a database? if not, what are the alternatives or the best way to store these files.

***EDIT:*** I would like to rephrase my question, is it possible to store individual files(.txt, .csv, etc) and not its contents to postgresql using Java JDBC?

Comment: As to whether it is good or not to dump binary data into the database, it depends upon how you want to backup and potentially replicate the data. There is no definitive answer without specific use cases. Generally with advanced optimization, using external files so storage arrays can dedup beats trying to keep stuff in the DB. Plus a lot of binary stuff in the DB makes backing up the DB a mess. YMMV.

Comment: So you want to store a file but not the content... Then what is the purpose of that, you are then storing nothing... In Postgres CLOB is defined by the TEXT type. (Check the documentation for that).

Comment: Use `text` if the file is text in a known encoding and you want it encoding converted by the database on input/output. Use `bytea` if you want to store the raw bytes, such as when you don't know the text encoding, it's not only text, or you want to avoid encoding conversion.

Answer (score 0):

uh, the TEXT data type is essentially a CLOB, isn't it?  However, if the files are large, storing in a database is rather a waste, there are better solutions such as a CMS (even some basic open source version) or even in the file system indexed somewhere.  Relational databases are great for structured data, but large BLOBs/CLOBs have overhead that can cause database performance problems unless you really know what you're doing.  Some, like Oracle, only allow a single BLOB/CLOB per table so that it can be managed "differently" while other vendors require you to stream out the content rather than just bind it to a string variable.  So regardless, be careful.

Comment: oh, I though TEXT and CLOB are different types. I got confused for reading a lot of resources. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Oracle absolutely allows more then one BLOB or CLOB column per table.

Comment: I've moved away from Oracle for a while, at the time it was one only.

Answer (score 0):

1. File store on local directory and process file from directory .
2. Write iterator pattern for reading file and store data in collection or array
3. Crud operation collection or array .